# Menus look strange and performance is poor after upgrade from Ubuntu 16.04 to 18.04

Tags: upgrade

Yesterday I upgraded from Ubuntu 16.04 to Ubuntu 18.04. After starting Ubuntu 18.04 I found my system working very slow and when I open terminal or any other application, the menu is looking very different and difficult to read.

[image: compressed menu items]

My system configuration is as below:

[image: screenshot of system info]

Any help will be appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: It's a font/theme choice I believe, sorry I can't see from the snippet if you are using GNOME (default for 18.04) or Unity (default for 16.04) so I'd try `gnome-tweaks` or `unity-tweak-tool` particularly the 'fonts' , or in 'appearance' (if it's theme).  You may need to logout/login back in to see full effect, but I'd hope you'd detect fix without logout/login.

Comment: I see a bit of a hint of an APT error "the following packages have been kept back" in your terminal screenshot. If `apt update` and other commands are showing errors, that might give a clue to what's causing your problem, so you might want to copy and paste that output into your question in an [edit] if it looks informative.

Answer (score 1):

I'm guessing that you managed to resolve this issue, but in case you didn't, or for anyone else that this might help; I found that after upgrading from 16.04 LTS to 18.04 LTS the styles were missing from my menus and settings, such as volume.

This seems due to the fact that I was using a GTK theme for 16.04. After setting all my icons, themes, cursor and fonts back to defaults, everything was usable again. You can use gnome-tweaks or unity-tweak-tool to do this if you are in a similar position.

Hope this might be helpful for someone.